# A good way to fetch data in a file

Tags: c, file, indexing, fetch

I'm working on a program which needs to get a code from an user input, and fetch data from a file with this code.

The file contains 15k lines in this format:

```
code-quantity
3014627896-1050
8015627493-1920
```

So I need to find the code in the file and then extract the quantity next to it.
At first I was thinking about browsing the file with `fgets()`, extract the code from each line and test if the user input is matching the current code.

I'm worried that it might be too slow, is there a better way to fetch data with an index in C? Thanks

Comment: 15k is not too much. Just use an array and read it all in: `struct data { char code[11]; int quantity; }; struct data data[20000]; /* some latitude */ int ndata; /* keep count */`

Comment: 15 K is not that many. Why don't you load that file into memory (in a suitable data structure) and do the searches in memory? I cannot imagine any faster method in C.

Comment: Your idea is not bad, and reading the whole file in memory is slower than reading (and parsing) only what needed. BTW: what do you with "index"? You described none.

Comment: Grammar Hint: You shouldn't write dataS but just data: [https://language-boutique.com/lost-in-translation-full-reader/these-data-are-or-this-data-is-.html](https://language-boutique.com/lost-in-translation-full-reader/these-data-are-or-this-data-is-.html)

Comment: Hi @linuxfan I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve the line wanted using the code as index. Is the process I described really faster than reading the whole file in memory, and then browsing the memory to find the line wanted ? I forgot to mention that the program is gonna search through data multiple times not just once.

Comment: About index: this is not possible. If the program will search multiple times, then of course is better to cache data in ram (provided you have enough).

Comment: Are the code numbers all the same length?  Are the quantities always 4 digits?  In other words, are the data entries all the same length?   And are the codes stored in a sorted order?  You have some searching options available if the codes are in sorted order that are not available if they’re in an indeterminate order.

Comment: The code numbers are all the same length and the quantity isn't always 4 digits, and the codes are stored in ascending order

Comment: Given that the code numbers are stored in sorted order and there are 15k of them, you might find that a binary search on the file works.  You have to read enough data to be sure you've got a complete record to work with; that would be at least two times the longest line (biggest quantity) plus the newlines.  You can then work through the file to find the right record in the usual binary search mode.